# kivymd android app crash on shadows with Adreno 506

Tags: android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer, p4a

Hi i am building kivymd android app, and its works fine. But if device have Adreno (506 in my case) GPU it crashes when you have any shades. I've tried to put

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

or

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030002" android:required="true"/>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml - it doesnt helps,
also i've tried to modify buildozer spec like

```
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1
```

or

```
osx.kivy_version = 2.2.0
```

app crashes without any debug info,
i've removed any shadow or elevation from my KV file, but i'am using a lot of MDDialog which has a shadow and elevation from the box.
Is there any way to:
Make shades work on Adreno? OR
Disable shades/shadow/elevation on MDDialog?